# Binding image with url from object passed in as a property

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue cli and I am passing an object from the parent component as a property into a child component.

This is one example of an object (in parent component but passed over as a prop)

```
{
        question: 'How many times is Jon stabbed when he is murdered at Castle Black?',
        choices: ['1', '6', '9', '10'],
        answer: '6',
        imgUrl: './src/assets/0.jpg'
    }
```

This is the image tag I'm trying to bind it to in the child component. questionIndex is just a number I'm using to be able to render the next question when the user moves to the next question.

```
<img :src="questions[questionIndex].imgUrl"/>
```

The error I'm getting is: 
GET http://localhost:8080/src/assets/0.jpg 404 (Not Found)

I'm able to render everything fine except the image. I believe it has something to with webpack but I'm not sure. I've tried looking at similar threads but all of them were folks trying to render a single image that has been passed as data from the vue instance. Whereas my case is different.

Just to make things clearer.. I'm trying to render in the Trivia component and the objects(props) are being passed in from the App component.

[image: Directory tree]

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/` points to the `build` directory. Use `imgUrl: '../../src/assets/0.jpg'`

Comment: yes! you should move your images to /build folder. Those are public files, not source files

Comment: imgUrl: '../../src/assets/0.jpg'. Unfortunately still didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dynamic files and images should be stored into the static folder and then reference the path while the root is the index.html

./static/images/0.jpg

Comment: Awesome, it worked. So just for clarification, images should always go into static? What is the assets folder for then?

Comment: assets is for static images and files which will not change from CMS system or something, like static Logo that is always there or fonts or even images/svgs that are used without dynamic path

Answer (score 0):

This is rough code. But vue user will get this.
Child :

```
<img :src="require(`@/assets/${image}`)">
props: ['image']
```

Parent:

```
<child-tag image="file.extension" />
```

src/assets: there should be file `file.extension`